# How to run binary file without debugging using gdb?

Tags: gdb, riscv

I am working with a RISCV core, specifically the [AIRISC](https://github.com/Fraunhofer-IMS/airisc_core_complex). I was able to get it working perfectly on a Nexys4 DDR.
I have tried to execute my code using gdb but now I need to do profiling. The problem is that according to the [user guide](https://fraunhofer-ims.github.io/airisc_core_complex/AIRI5C_UserGuide_en.html#software-development-on-the-airisc) gdb seems to be the only way to run the binary file but seams to add a lot of overhead.

The connections are made similarly to the image below:

[image]

I tried to execute the code by connecting OpenOCD through the dongle and then starting a gdb session on port 3333.
Doing so, I use the following command:

```
file main.elf
delete breakpoints
load
continue
```

As the application start I detach immediately the debugger (or at least I think to do so) by pressing CTRL+C on OpenOCD. But it is still slow.

Since using gdb is the only way there seems to be to run applications with this core, I wanted to ask if there is effectively an overhead that is added and how I can overcome this problem.